TranslateTransform not being "preserved" when applying RotateTransform to a WPF TextBlock in a Canvas
When plotting some TextBlocks along with other shapes in a canvas, I place them using the TranslateTransform.
I am not doing it in XAML because I will generate the objects in run-time.
Point origin, rotated;
origin.X = center.X;
origin.Y = center.Y + radius;
rotated.X = (Math.Cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * (origin.X - center.X) - Math.Sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * (origin.Y - center.Y) + center.X);
rotated.Y = (Math.Sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * (origin.X - center.X) + Math.Cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * (origin.Y - center.Y) + center.Y);

TranslateTransform translateTransf = new TranslateTransform() { X = rotated.X, Y = rotated.Y };
textBlock.RenderTransform = translateTransf;
plotCanvas.Children.Add(textBlock);


And then in another event I apply a rotation to objects in the canvas, with the absolute values of the canvas passed to CenterX and CenterY to determine the center of all rotations.
RotateTransform rotateTransf = new RotateTransform(angleRotation) { CenterX = plotCanvas.ActualHeight / 2, CenterY = plotCanvas.ActualWidth / 2 };
foreach (TextBlock childBlock in plotCanvas.Children.OfType<TextBlock>())
    childBlock.RenderTransform = rotateTransf;
// Other objects are rotated fine around the canvas center

When the event triggers, the effect of the TranslateTransform previously applied somehow is "lost" and the textblocks are placed at what seems to be (0, 0) of the canvas and then they are rotated. The other shapes rotate fine, I used ellipses and lines as geometries and placed them at the positions I needed and weren't subject to a TranslateTransform.
And notice that a "secondary rotation" is applied to the (bunched up) text, while I expected it to stay horizontal and then I would apply another rotation to have it pointing to the center of the canvas.

What am I doing wrong, or missing, in order to "preserve" the initial transform just before the rotation (or accumulate transforms), and why is this "secondary rotation" happening?

How to: Apply Multiple Transforms to an Object

@emoacht thanks. This page provides the info I needed, as I didn't know about TransformGroup. I will find a way to preserve the translation and only keep updating the rotation because that's the transform I will be applying often. The translation will always be there, so to speak. Can you post an answer so I can accept it?

I also came across some posts saying it is possible to update RenderTransform instead of replacing it, for performance's sake and I could see it myself when trying TransformGroup, but they don't say how it can be updated instead of replaced (using the = operator, which is all I know). Sources are: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780865/wpf-animation-best-practices and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-layout-and-design?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

IMHO, replacing a Transform at run time is relatively rare. In contrast, manipulating the value of Transform so as to animate an object is quite common. For example https://stackoverflow.com/a/692913/3137337

I would still advise you to switch to the typical for WPF creation and management of UI elements in XAML. The fact that you create dynamic objects in Sharpe's code does not at all impede this approach.

I expect that if everything is on a single Canvas (ellipses, lines and textblocks), then rotating the Canvas would give you what you want. I typically use UserControls; calculate their center point, and rotate the whole thing around that.

@GerrySchmitz thanks for your input. Now that I learned about the transforms and group, and then made the thing work, I feel more comfortable encapsulating that in a UC.

I'll show an example implementation without using Code Behind.
Although general answers are not welcome here (on stackOwerflow) and this answer will most likely be removed.
But it will be useful for you to know about alternative implementation methods.
namespace Core2024.SO.JayY.question78465615
{
    public class SomeObject
    {
        private string _text = string.Empty;

        public double Left { get; set; }
        public double Top { get; set; }
        public double Lenght { get; set; }

        public double Angle { get; set; }

        public string Text { get => _text; set => _text = value ?? string.Empty; }

        public SomeObject() { }
        public SomeObject(double left, double top, double lenght, double angle, string? text = null)
        {
            if (text is null)
            {
                text = string.Format("""{0:0}, {1:0}, {2:0}, {3:0}""", left, top, lenght, angle);
            }

            Left = left;
            Top = top;
            Lenght = lenght;
            Angle = angle;
            Text = text;

        }
    }
}

// This is the space with my RelayCommand implementation
using Simplified;

using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Core2024.SO.JayY.question78465615
{
    public class SomeViewModel
    {
        public int Count { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<SomeObject> SomeObjects { get; } = new();

        public double CanvasWidth { get; } = 400;
        public double CanvasHeight { get; } = 300;

        private void ReCreateObjects(int count)
        {
            SomeObjects.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                SomeObjects.Add(new SomeObject
                (
                    Random.Shared.NextDouble() * CanvasWidth,
                    Random.Shared.NextDouble() * CanvasHeight,
                    Random.Shared.NextDouble() * 100+100,
                    Random.Shared.NextDouble() * 360
                ));
            }
        }

        public SomeViewModel() => ReCreateObjects(4);

        private RelayCommand? _reCreateCommand;
        public RelayCommand ReCreateCommand => _reCreateCommand
            ??= new RelayCommand<int>(ReCreateObjects);
    }
}

<Window x:Class="Core2024.SO.JayY.question78465615.SomeObjectsWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2024.SO.JayY.question78465615"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="SomeObjectsWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        DataContext="{DynamicResource vm}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:SomeViewModel x:Key="vm"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SomeObjects}"
                      BorderBrush="Aqua"
                      BorderThickness="2">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas Width="{Binding CanvasWidth, Mode=OneWay}"
                            Height="{Binding CanvasHeight, Mode=OneWay}"
                            Margin="10,10,100,100"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SomeObject}">
                    <StackPanel RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Angle}"/>
                        </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"
                                   TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        <Line X2="{Binding Lenght}"
                              Stroke="Green"
                              StrokeThickness="2"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}"/>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ItemsControl>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding Count}" Margin="5"/>
            <Button Content="Render"
                    Command="{Binding ReCreateCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding Count}"
                    Padding="15 5"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>



Thanks for your input, EldHasp. I have no problem accepting your post as answer because it addresses not only my initial question, but possibly others. I am working on a TransformGroup and building the stack of transforms that my objects need, and I want to ask if the RenderTransformOrigin=(0.5, 0.5) can somehow go in the TransformGroup instead. As you might guess, part of the process requires a rotation of 90 degrees around the object's center, but everything else will be around the canvas center.

@JayY RenderTransformOrigin is a property of the UI element, so it applies to all transformations.
But you can set the rotation center in RotateTransform  <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Angle}" CenterX="10" CenterY="20"/>. Just note that the center is thus defined in absolute coordinates, and not in relative ones.

You can also place elements in yet another common additional container (for example, a Panel or ContentControl) which will have its own independent transformation. This way you will be able to separately set the center for different groups of animations.

Thanks for your considerations. I ended up applying the rotation at (0, 0) of the canvas and then just compensated for that in the translation that came after this. I got piles of information from Emoacht who pointed me to TransformGroup, the SO post I referred bellow which saves computing time by updating the steps of the TransformGroup, and now from you with this generalist example above. All of that allowed me to move one, so I will just mark your answer.

I managed to do the most efficient, to the best of my knowledge from the hours researching this topic, update of an element of a TransformGroup (in my case, a RotateTransform) instead of reapplying the transforms to RenderTransform. Thanks to @emoacht for letting me know about TransformGroup.
For those interested, this one line changes the angle of the RotationTransform, which is the second child of my TransformGroup (first is a TranslateTransform):
((RotateTransform)((TransformGroup)childBlock.RenderTransform).Children[1]).Angle = angleRotation;

This is assuming I already have CenterX and CenterY populated. In case they are not, then just precede the above line with the following and change to what you need (in my case I am rotating around the center of the canvas):
((RotateTransform)((TransformGroup)childBlock.RenderTransform).Children[1]).CenterX = cv.ActualHeight / 2;
((RotateTransform)((TransformGroup)childBlock.RenderTransform).Children[1]).CenterY = cv.ActualWidth / 2;

This idea came from the following S.O. post:
WPF change transforms in c#
